# How to add slide animation?

Tags: ios, uitableview, xamarin, uiview, xamarin.ios

Can I make animation like that: on swipe to top hide view and expand table view. On down swipe show view.

I illustrated what I want on the screenshot below:

[image: screenshot]

Comment: Do you mean you want a header on your table view?

Comment: No, it is custom view with calendar and some data

Comment: Not a direct answer but: Create a table, row 0 - your view, row 0 too - your table. Now set initial table TranslationY so it doesnt cover your view. Add swipe gesturerecognizer, react to swipe with YourTable.TranslateTo(0,0, easing sinout ) to open table, and YourTable.TranslateTo(0,YourInitialTableY, easing sinout ) to close it

Answer (score 0):

In Xamarin IOS , you can have a try with using `UIScrollView` .Setting `PagingEnabled` be ture , can realize your want.(Follow ScrollView is also full screen in `StoryBoard`)

```
ScrollView.ContentSize = new CGSize(UIScreen.MainScreen.Bounds.Size.Width, 2*ScrollView.Bounds.Size.Height);
ScrollView.PagingEnabled = true;
```

TableView code:

```
UITableView uITableView = new UITableView(new CGRect(0, ScrollView.Bounds.Size.Height, UIScreen.MainScreen.Bounds.Size.Width, ScrollView.Bounds.Size.Height));
string[] tableItems = new string[] { "Vegetables", "Fruits", "Flower Buds", "Legumes", "Bulbs", "Tubers", "Vegetables", "Fruits", "Flower Buds", "Legumes", "Bulbs", "Tubers"};
uITableView.BackgroundColor = UIColor.Cyan;
uITableView.Source = new TableSource(tableItems);

public class TableSource : UITableViewSource
{
    string[] TableItems;
    string CellIdentifier = "TableCell";

    public TableSource(string[] items)
    {
        TableItems = items;
    }
    public override UITableViewCell GetCell(UITableView tableView, NSIndexPath indexPath)
    {
        UITableViewCell cell = tableView.DequeueReusableCell(CellIdentifier);
        string item = TableItems[indexPath.Row];

        //---- if there are no cells to reuse, create a new one
        if (cell == null)
        { cell = new UITableViewCell(UITableViewCellStyle.Default, CellIdentifier); }

        cell.TextLabel.Text = item;

        return cell;
    }

    public override nint RowsInSection(UITableView tableview, nint section)
    {
        return TableItems.Length;
    }
}
```

Custom a up view:

```
UIView upView = new UIView(new CGRect(0, 0, UIScreen.MainScreen.Bounds.Size.Width, ScrollView.Bounds.Size.Height));
upView.BackgroundColor = UIColor.DarkGray;
```

Last add them in ScrollView:

```
ScrollView.Add(upView);
ScrollView.Add(uITableView);
```

Image show as follow:(For better show different page in ScrollView, setting background color for upView and uITableView)

[image][image]

When entering this controller, set ContentOffSet be second page, then will show tableview first , and when you scroll down , upView will show there.

```
ScrollView.SetContentOffset(new CGPoint(0, ScrollView.Bounds.Size.Height), true);
```

If want to add Animation when scrolling , adding a `Delegate` to listen `DraggingStarted`

```
ScrollView.Delegate = new ScrollViewDelegate();

public class ScrollViewDelegate :UIScrollViewDelegate
{


    public override void DraggingStarted(UIScrollView scrollView)
    {
        //base.DraggingStarted(scrollView);
        if(scrollView.ContentOffset.Y == scrollView.Bounds.Size.Height)
        {
            //Add Animation herer
        }
    }
}
```